# the trajectory cannonball shot from the ground in c

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, physics

I started to learn to code last year.Not very good though.
I tried to plot the trajectory of cannonball shot from the ground using c language. (I didn't code this alone anyway).

(# sorry I have to delete the original code for a while. If you would like to see my original code, please let me know. but I'm sure it'd be totally enough if you just see　the selected answer below.　)

and if I excute it, the result is like this.

```
the speed is?
6
the angle is
32
the spring is
0.4
X=0.000000, Y=0.000000
X=0.000000, Y=-0.049000
X=0.000000, Y=-0.049000
X=0.000000, Y=-0.049000
X=0.000000, Y=-0.049000
X=0.000000, Y=-0.049000
X=0.000000, Y=-0.049000
X=0.000000, Y=-0.049000
X=0.000000, Y=-0.049000
X=0.000000, Y=-0.049000
```

I tried to figure out what I did wrong, but I have no idea at all.
Please help me!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: It depends on what number I insert as speed, angle and coeff of restitution, but X should keep increasing and Y should draw parabola.

Comment: and Y probably bounces a couple times.

Comment: Where do you update `time`?

Comment: in while loop, I coded time=time+0.1. Sorry t=time+0.1 was a typo.

Comment: There is no variable I can see named `t`, this code doesn't compile, and the printf statements don't match your example run.

Comment: Always post actual code.  Too much time is wasted finding "typos" that are not related to the problem.

Comment: sorry t=time+0.1 was a typo. actually when I first coded I named time variable just "t". i changed it to time when I posted this here coz it would make it easier to read for other people.

Comment: Just copy the original code and press "Ctrl + K". Then you have the indentation... Still the expected output is missing.

Comment: This may be what you want. I fixed the time typo and used time instead of the missing t variable. https://ideone.com/Vlvp0t

Comment: OK I'll post this tomorrow again because I coded this at school. It is late at night here. thank you guys.

Comment: thanks a lot retired ninja. I'll check it out tomorrow at school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this approach is that the Y-coordinate can become negative. And once it does, if the initial speed is not high enough, the ball can become stuck underneath the surface, as demonstrated by `@RetiredNinja`'s results (the coordinate becomes stuck at `-0.049` at some point which is not the correct behavior).

Erroneous results (not to scale) from original code, with modified parameters:

[image]

The ball seems to "tunnel" through the ground (some values dip below zero).

---

How to resolve this? We need to resolve the collision properly, making sure that the ball bounces instead of crossing the surface boundary. To do so, let's examine the behavior of the ball during a timestep in which a bounce occurs.

[image]

A collision occurs when both the vertical velocity and vertical position are negative. To find the collision time and velocity, use the equations of motion:

[image]

Once we have the collision velocity, we can simply update the new vertical speed to `-spring * vc` (`spring` should have a better name, e.g. `coef_rest`); an additional advantage is that we no longer need calls to `pow`.

This may occur several times during a timestep, so we need to perform this in a loop. One more thing to watch out for is that as the vertical velocity decays, the bounces become infinitely more frequent - so we need a "cut-off" velocity at which to stop the ball from bouncing.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.141592654
#endif

int main()
{
   const double g = 9.81;        // gravity
   const double dt = 0.025;      // time step
   const double maxtime = 5.0;   // max time
   const double spring = 0.95;   // coefficient of restitution
   const double cutoff = 1e-4;   // cut-off velocity

   double speed = 6;
   double angle = 32;
   angle = angle * M_PI / 180.0;

   double init_vx = speed * cos(angle);
   double init_vy = speed * sin(angle);

   int springnumber = 0;

   printf("0.0,0.0\n");
   for (double ts = 0.0, vs = init_vy, time = dt; time <= maxtime;)
   {
      // positions *after* this time step
      double px = time * init_vx;
      double elapse = time - ts;
      double py = 0.0, vy = 0.0;
      if (vs >= cutoff)
      {
         py = (vs - 0.5 * g * elapse) * elapse;
         vy = vs - g * elapse;
      }

      // check for bounce
      if (vy < 0.0 && py < 0.0)
      { 
         // collision time
         double tc = 2.0 * vs / g;

         // update speed after bounce and time of collision
         springnumber++;
         vs *= spring;
         ts += tc;

         continue;
      }

      // print
      printf("%f,%f\n", px, py);

      // timestep
      time += dt;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Test results, with the same parameters as before:

[image]

The ball no longer "tunnels", which is the correct behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot meowgoesthedog, your answer is really helpful. By the way, I have a question. Why is it ok to multiply the the speed of y direction by 0.95, not -0.95? I thought it should be a negative number as the ball changes the direction when it bounces. well when i changed it to -0.95, graph looks definitely weird though.

Comment: Oh, now i get it(maybe). It's because the elapse becomes zero when it hits the ground, so vy becomes positive. Thanks!

Comment: And then things get a lot more fun when you introduce the *coefficient of restitution* related to the impact and the ground, the mass moment of inertia of the cannon ball, the rotational speed to the cannon ball, the coefficients of friction (both static and sliding) between the ball and the ground and so on and so forth...

Comment: @DavidCRankin 1) the coefficient is already present as `spring`, 2) this is only a basic simulation (meant as an exercise) where the ball is modelled as a point object, so these do not apply.